# AspectJ pointcut to method call in specific methods

Tags: java, aspectj

I want to create a pointcut to target a call to a method from specific methods.

take the following:

```
class Parent {
   public foo() {
     //do something
   }
}

class Child extends Parent {
   public bar1() {
     foo();
   }
   public bar2() {
     foo();
   }
   public bar3() {
     foo();
   }
}
```

I would like to have a point cut on the call to foo() in methods bar1() and bar3()

I was thinking something like

```
pointcut fooOperation(): call(public void Parent.foo() && (execution(* Child.bar1()) || execution(* Child.bar3()) );

before() : fooOperation() {
  //do something else
}
```

however, that doesnt seem to work. any ideas?

thanks

Answer (score 3):

Maybe `withincode` will work:

```
call(public void Parent.foo()) && (withincode(* Child.bar1()) || withincode(* Child.bar3()) );
```

Alternatively you could try the `cflow` pointcut:

```
pointcut bar1(): call(* Child.bar1());
pointcut bar3(): call(* Child.bar3());

call(public void Parent.foo()) && (cflow(bar1()) || cflow(bar3());
```

Look here for a [pointcut reference](http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/released/progguide/semantics-pointcuts.html)

Answer (score 2):

Think what you want is instead of doing the execution clauses (which have the added disadvantage of requiring additions for each new caller), is to use target, e.g. something like:

```
target(Child) && call(public void Parent.foo()).
```

Somewhat surprisingly, I have found the pointcut guides in the eclipse documentation quite useful. They are [here](http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/released/progguide/language-joinPoints.html).

Comment: I'd say this one would also match the call to `foo()` in `bar2()`, contrary to the intention?

Comment: yes, that would catch the `foo()` in `bar2()`, which is not what is intended

Comment: Haha. Here's a recommendation: if you want to capture foo() from bar2..barn, use my point cut and ignore the call to foo from bar1. Coming in and changing that definition each time a new bar is added is not very bueno.