# How to Achieve AspectJ "withincode" in Spring AOP

Tags: java, aspectj, spring-aop

I'm aware that Spring AOP is limited to certain numbers of pointcut designators. Is there a way out to achieve withincode?

Right now I'm inspecting the stacktrace to to check where it was called. Is there a more decent/cleaner way?

Comment: I don't understand well your needs but do you want to create an aspect to your method execution? In that case you @Around example in [this page](http://www.mkyong.com/spring3/spring-aop-aspectj-annotation-example/)

Comment: I want to achieve AspectJ "withincode" poincut designator using the combination of available pointcut designators in Spring AOP. Please check the link to see the available pointcut designators in Spring AOP [Spring AOP](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html)

Comment: I looked for some samples and think [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6500399/aspectj-pointcut-to-method-call-in-specific-methods/7480565#7480565) can help you.

Comment: That could help, but as I mentioned in my question I'm using Spring AOP(limited pointcut designators) not the pure implementation of AspectJ.